# How to use the long section caption for bookmarks with hyperref

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

The package `hyperref` uses the short caption of a section for the bookmark entry. Is it possible to use the long form instead?
I have many sections so manually adding all of them to the bookmarks is not an option.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,pdfencoding=auto,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section[Short title for toc]{A very long title which should also be visible as bookmark}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all long section, subsection etc. titles should appear in the bookmarks, perhaps the easiest way is to shift the `\toclevel@...` to something far beyond the real levels, say add `1000`, add the normal contentsline and use and explicit `\pdfbookmark[...]{...}{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}{%
  \csletcs{orig@toclevel}{toclevel@#1}%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname toclevel@#1\endcsname{\the\numexpr#2+1000}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
   \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
  \pdfbookmark[#2]{#8}{\csname theH#1\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname toclevel@#1\endcsname{\orig@toclevel}% Restore
}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,pdfencoding=auto,hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section[Short title for toc]{A very long title which should also be visible as bookmark}
\blindtext[5]
\section[Another Short title for toc]{Another very very long title which should also be visible as bookmark}
\blindtext[6]
\subsection{A subsection title}
\section[Yet another Short title for toc]{Yet another very very long title which should also be visible as bookmark}
\blindtext[6]

\subsection{Another subsection title}

\subsubsection[Short subsubsection]{Another long long subsubsection title}

\subsection[Short subsection title one level higher]{Another short subsection title one level higher}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, `hyperref` hooks into `\addcontentsline` for making the bookmark entry, so other approaches would need to modify the whole structure.